# WPF How to make DataGrid blank out certain columns based on a value in one of bound columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

I have a DataGrid that should display values from a datatable object.

I need it to display one row for each in the datatable, but if column ShowRow in the DataTable is set to False, I need all but the first 2 column to display nothing. Right now I am achieving this by binding to a copy of the table and in that copy I manually set the values to empty when needed.

Is there a more elegant way to do this through binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create your custom `IValueConverter` and for values that should be hidden convert to empty string

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through data triggers.

Example:

- You create a custom **DataGridCell** style called **MyCellStyle**.
- Whenever the property **MyProperty** contained in the specific model representing the row is set to **True** the ForeGround text will be set to Transparent.
- All you need to do is utilize this on any **DataGridCell** that you wish to exhibit the desired behavior.

The sample:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- Hide text if MyProperty is "True" -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />            
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

There are of course other options for hiding the text. I would strongly recommend not manipulating the model itself. Affect the content visibility instead since that is the desired behavior.

Comment: I see that this is viable but I need them to be able to select text in datagrid, and this would let them see the invisible cells.